# Skipping serialization of a variant if its value is empty? (custom serialization)

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

I want to skip serialization of `Token` variant if its value is empty.

```rust
impl<'a> Serialize for UriParam<'a> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where S: Serializer
    {
        match self {
            &UriParam::Token(ref token) => {
                if !token.is_empty() {
                    serializer.serialize_some(token)
                } else {
                    // what should I return instead?
                }
            },
            &UriParam::URI(ref uri) => serializer.serialize_some(uri),
            &UriParam::Param(ref option) => serializer.serialize_some(option),
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
serializer.serialize_none()
```

[This serializes `None` (as opposed to `Some`)](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/trait.Serializer.html#tymethod.serialize_none)